# http://m.bing.com/directions parameters?

Tags: ios, bing-maps

Hi all I need to know on how to pass two points (longitude and latitude) in http://m.bing.com/directions? to draw a route and show driving directions to the user.

I had find a solution by trial and error in this is the resulting URL: http://m.bing.com/directions?IIG=acc63aafc7ac4348b2fa7662d871504a&kval=3.1&appns=mSERP&cutc=1362555191520#/Maps?q=37.332333,-122.031219,,,,current%20location~42.983391,-81.233040,,,,current%20location&ul=&mode=1&autoredirect=0

I'm passing this from my app to safari mobile.

I need to know a proper way of passing two point and also if there are other parameters if there are any.

I googled for many hours and nothing is resolved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use the same parameters than with the bing maps portal, see the documentation here and if the user is using a mobile platform, he should be redirected to the mobile version:

http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/ff808440.aspx

Here is also an interesting article from Alastair on his blog:

http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/url-parameters-for-the-bing-maps-website/